# Fragment view is not outputting

Tags: android

I have a fragment called TabFragment, which contains an ImageAdapter. Now the ImageAdapter will create an imageView which I attached an onclick listener to it. Once the imageView is clicked I would like to open the DetailsFragment fragment. However open pressing upon the imageView, the Toast messages are shown meaning that the specific fragments are accessed, but the actual view of the fragment is not.

**ImageAdapter class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public ImageAdapter(Context c,FragmentManager fm) {
    mContext = c;
    fragmentManager = fm;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageURI(mThumbIds[position]);
    //check for tap
    if(imageView.getDrawable() != null)
    {
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Fragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,detailsFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    return imageView;
}



private Uri[] mThumbIds = new Uri[20];

public void setUriArr(Uri[] uriArr){
    this.mThumbIds = uriArr;
}
```

}

**DetailsFragment Class**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "entered fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**TabFragment fragment** [just in case]

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment{

    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);
        LoadGridView(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LoadGridView(rootView);
    }

    public void LoadGridView(View v){
        GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.grdvwImages);
        ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),getFragmentManager());

        int i = 0;
        Uri[] imageArray = new Uri[20];
        int pos = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
        //DeleteAll();
        List<GalleryModel> news = GetNewsArticles(pos);

        if(news.size() != 0){

            for(GalleryModel n:news){
                imageArray[i] = Uri.parse(n.imageDir);
                i++;
            }
            ia.setUriArr(imageArray);
        }
        gridview.setAdapter(ia);

    }


    public List<GalleryModel> GetNewsArticles(int position){
        return new Select()
                .from(GalleryModel.class)
                .where("Section = ?", position)
                .execute();
    }

    public void DeleteAll()
    {
        new Delete().from(GalleryModel.class).execute();
    }


}
```

**fragment_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jerome_pc.myfirstapp.PortalActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="587dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-5dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-1dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Post Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Post Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:onClick="btnCancelOnClick"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnSubmitOnClick"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace instead of add

```
            Fragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,detailsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**EDIT: remove absolute x and y from relativelayout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="587dp">
```

and check your version of constraint-layout in gradle

**EDIT2: organize your code**

create click listener for the image in the imageadapter like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private ImageAdapterClick imageAdapterListener;

public interface ImageAdapterClick {

    void isClicked();
}

public ImageAdapter(Context c,FragmentManager fm, ImageAdapterClick imageAdapterListener) {
mContext = c;
fragmentManager = fm;
this.imageAdapterListener = imageAdapterListener;
}
```

then change local listener in the getView method

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           imageAdapterListener.isClicked();

       }
    });
```

then in your TabFragment change the adapter in the way which would call that details fragment

```
 ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),getFragmentManager(), new 
 ImageAdapter.ImageAdapterClick (){
        @Override
        public void isClicked() {

        Fragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,detailsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

       }
    });
```

Comment: Replace removes all the content in the container however still the new fragment is not visible.

Comment: then obviously is something wrong with the layout. post the R.layout.fragment_details

Comment: Okay it was added.

Comment: I checked my x and y values and arranged them to match the container parent, however still no progress.

Comment: Also I removed the absolute x and y values from the relative layout still nothing.

Comment: Then reorganize your code because calling fragment this way is wrong. check my second edit

Comment: I have re-arranged my code structure as you have instructed but it seems it's all in  vain.

Comment: I think the fragment is being created, however the layout is not being displayed.